# selecting value in dropdown and verify on page

Tags: selenium, selenium-rc

I have one dropdown that contains 6 values.

Actual scenario is if you select any value from dropdown then the selected value will appear in next page

for eg: I selected city Mumbai from dropdown, then on next page Mumbai city is selected will appear as text.

I want to verify the selected value is appearing correctly on next page.

Comment: You may like to add the code.

Answer (score 0):

To click the option

```
Select select = new Select(driver.findElement(By.xpath("//path_to_drop_down")));
select.deselectAll();
select.selectByVisibleText("Value1");
```

There are many more methods and you can choose how you locate the element. I suggest give name to each one and *findElement by Name*

To assert presence -

Use something like

```
public boolean verifyTextInField(String expectedValue, By by) {
    try {
        assertEquals(expectedValue,
                driver.findElement(by).getAttribute("value"));
        System.out.println("Values are equal");
        return true;
    } catch (Error e) {
        verificationErrors.append(e.toString());
        System.out.println("Values are unequal");
        return false;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

for selection element in dropdown u can use js executor :

```
String cssLocator=....
JavascriptExecutor js = (JavascriptExecutor) driver;
        StringBuilder stringBuilder = new StringBuilder();
        stringBuilder.append("var x = $(\'"+cssLocator+"\');");
        stringBuilder.append("x.click();");
        js.executeScript(stringBuilder.toString());
```

Then switch to the dropdown and get value switched:

`String dropdownValue=driver.findElement(By.xpath("..."))).getText().trim();` //something like that
then u can switch to the text label on next page

```
String labelValue= driver.findElement(By.xpath("..."))).getText().trim();
```

and compare two stings: dropdownValue  and labelValue

Hope this helps you